# Overhead of preserve tcp connection

Tags: sockets, tcp

I'm new to socket programming. I am wondering what is the internet and hardware overhead of create a TCP connection and let it be idle?

For example, There are1000 clients, each creates a tcp connection to a single server and after tcp connection established, at this point what is the internet or hardware overhead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [3-way TCP handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment) that takes place to establish a TCP connection.

After the connection has been established, the only data that flows through the connection is what the applications send and, if enabled, [TCP keep-alives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keepalive#TCP_keepalive) (TCP segment with 0 payload).